# How to load camera data before starting Angular MatBottomSheet

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I would like to embed the qr-code scanner (https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner) into a bottom sheet in my Angular App. To get camera information I am using in my scanning component (bottom sheet) the following code:

```
@ViewChild('scanner')
scanner:ZXingScannerComponent;
hasCameras = false;
hasPermission: boolean;
availableDevices: MediaDeviceInfo[];
selectedDevice: MediaDeviceInfo;
ngOnInit() {
this.scanner.camerasFound.subscribe((devices: MediaDeviceInfo[]) => {
  this.hasCameras = true;

  console.log('Devices: ', devices);
  this.availableDevices = devices;

  //select camera if only one is available
  if (this.availableDevices.length <= 1) {
    this.selectedDevice = this.availableDevices[0];
  }
  else {
    //selects the devices's back camera by default
    for (const device of devices) {
      if (/back|rear|environment/gi.test(device.label)) {
        this.scanner.changeDevice(device);
        this.selectedDevice = device;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('selected Device: ' + this.selectedDevice);
});}
```

Unfortunately I don't get the camera data via subscription before the bottom sheet is rendered so the scanner doesn't work because no camera data is available at that moment.

html of my scanning component (bottom sheet):

```
  <zxing-scanner #scanner class="scanner" start="true" [device]="selectedDevice" (scanSuccess)="handleQrCodeResult($event)"></zxing-scanner>
```

html of the component which invokes the scanning component:

```
  scan() {

const scanSheet = this.bottomSheet.open(ScanningComponent, {
  panelClass: 'bottomSheet'
}); }
```

Did anybody already face this issue?

**UPDATE:**
I solved it by calling *this.ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();*
This updates my camera data and starts the scanner.

Comment: It would help to have the HTML attached as well.
For starters, did you try adding ``*ngIf="selectedDevice"`` to the ``zxing-scanner``element?

Comment: I tried that and get the following error:
ScanningComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'camerasFound' of undefined

Comment: Seems like the ``scanner`` property is still unset by the time you call ``this.scanner.camerasFound.subscribe``. Did you make sure to initialize it on the controller (either manually or through dependency injection)? It would really help if you posted the entirety of the component.

Comment: I think the problem is that camera data from subscription is not yet received when bottom sheet view is rendered.

Comment: That's why you'd want to add *ngIf to prevent it from rendering until you ca feed it the data. The problem, based on your error message, is ``this.scanner`` is ``undefined``.